# read data from HDFS root folder and append it to the Spark DF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading JSON files from a HDFS folder in Spark Scala

Code:

```
val path = "hdfs://year/month/date/*"
var df = spark.read.format("json").load(path)
```

So it reads all the part--JSON files in the date folder.

But I want to read all the JSON files in the year folder and append it to the DF. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val path = "hdfs://year/*/*/*"
var df = spark.read.format("json").load(path)
```

This worked.